# Image storage in a blob field coding in VB on MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've been tasked to modify a badge photo system for our employees. This might be simple but I'm new to coding in VB. The system controls the camera to take a picture of the new employee and printed on their new badge. Currently the photos are stored in a folder, saved and retrieved. I don't see anything wrong, but they want this changed to store in the database, MySQL. I've been researching, not large images, all small and only talking about 500 records at the most. So, figure a blob would be good start. Can you store a jpg in a blob. How do you save and retrieve? If anyone has done this before, just how you insert and retrieve code example and I'm probably off to the races.  Tks in advance...

Comment: Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469562-Saving-Images-in-Databases) out.

Comment: "they want this changed to store in the database". Why? usually it's bad for application performance, even if the images are relatively small. What advantage is anticpated? I would challenge the business case for this requirement, personally, especially if the existing system works well.

Comment: Storing images to a folder is much more efficient and involves no code to transform the image data.  That said, this doesnt show much effort on the (non) problem.  There are many many posts here on the topic.

Comment: The business case is that this small gate badge app. was created years ago. Since then the app has been installed and moved around in many locations. So, images taken at one location aren't at another if someone needs a badge replacement.  The app nor the image location aren't on a central server. Your bus. arg. is what I tried, I'm just a contractor for a short time, so doing this as directed.  Looking but can't find an example of saving and retrieving from a field/column in a MySQL table via VB6.  I'll keep looking... Tks

Comment: "via VB6". You tagged VB.NET. Is it actually a VB6 app? I doubt there's a mySQL connector for VB6, although I guess it would use a generic ODBC connection, so perhaps that's what you need to search under. But just because the app was moved around different locations doesn't mean they couldn't have copied all the images at the same time (why didn't they think of that??, or that they can't simply start hosting/storing them in a consistent central location (shared network folder??) now and solve the problem that way instead of re-writing. But sounds like maybe logic isn't their strong point

Comment: No the guy I'm working under is a good dude.  I agree with you and I brought up the subject again, maybe make the app. a server app. and I can mod. the code to not allow the user to save the images for a new badge wherever they want but hard coded to a directory on the same server as the app. His issue is with the network admin. I won't go into a long story but it's political here and the company is being taken over by a global company. So, just following orders, Ha! Also, I found some good examples for VB6 I think...

Comment: Using VBx, don't know the version nor care. Not a MS sort of guy. Never programmed in VB, just C, PHP and Delphi (object pascal) years ago. Here, programming VB with MS Visual Studio 2015. MySQL database.

Comment: This a good start... 
Public Sub SaveImage(filename As String, image As Image)
    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, filename & ".jpg")
    Dim mySource As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height)
    Dim grfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(mySource)
    grfx.DrawImageUnscaled(image, Point.Empty)
    grfx.Dispose()
    mySource.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    mySource.Dispose()
End Sub

Comment: Then add this code under Button or other executable place.
    Dim x As Integer = PictureBox1.Width
    Dim y As Integer = PictureBox1.Height
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(x, y)
    PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, x, y))
PictureBox1.Image = bm
'// Save The Visible Part of PictureBox Only (.....Cropped.....)
    SaveImage("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1" & ".jpg", bm)
'// Save The image in PictureBox in its Original size.
    SaveImage("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1" & ".jpg", PictureBox1.image)

Comment: "Using VBx, don't know the version nor care". Ok but VB6 and VB.NET are _completely_ different beasts. The syntax has similarities but pretty much that's where it ends. One's totally legacy stuff which compiles direct to a Win32 exe, the other runs under the .NET Framework. Different IDEs, different system libraries, different runtimes, different conventions. You need to know what you're using. What you've posted in the comments above looks like VB.NET. If you're using VS2015 as you mentioned then the app is almost certainly .NET and not VB6, which is a good thing (as it's not legacy code).

Comment: VB.net.  This has been put on hold for the time being here, been assigned other tasks.  But, need to learn how to do this in the next week or so. ADyson, If you have done this before, would greatly appreciate your share on how to do this. Tks...